# How to get the duration of all operations in SQL Sentry Plan Explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing a stored procedure and want to get the duration of all the procedure, but I get only the duration of each block.

[image]

How to do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: There isn't really a way to see total duration in the grid in the free version, since we "flatten" the call stack and don't show the enclosing proc call, what let to it, etc. In the PRO version, [the full stack feature will let you see this (click for an example)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F2wIh.png). What you can do in the free version is right-click that top grid, choose Copy > All, and paste into Excel. In Excel you can perform all kinds of aggregates that you need.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks, that's answers to my question, you can change the answer to a Post answer, so you will get the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer in the following pages:

[Measuring Query Performance : "Execution Plan Query Cost" vs "Time Taken"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564717/measuring-query-performance-execution-plan-query-cost-vs-time-taken)

and

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24617/can-i-get-ssms-to-show-me-the-actual-query-costs-in-the-execution-plan-pane

Comment: Can you write the answer here please? I didn't find there an answer that helps me.

Comment: This is another question and another answer. It does not shows him the duration, for me it shows... (But not of all together)